# Why don’t we say ״המלביש ערומים״ in the morning blessings?

Tags: blessing, grammar-dikduk, hamotzi-beracha

It says (Yerushalmi Berachos 6:1) that the reason we don’t say ״motzi lechem min ha’aretz”(which would have been more preferable) but “hamotzi”, is in order to separate between the מ״ם of “ha’olam” and the מ״ם of “hamotzi”.

Now my question is: why don’t we we do the same by the blessing of ״malbish arumim”?

Here is a possible answer I thought of: the difference between מוציא/מלביש and המוציא/המלביש is that the first - in this context - means: “the extractor/dresser of…” - which sounds more like past tense - he already did the act attributed to him, and the latter means: he who extracts/dresses - which is continuous - past, present and future (see Berachos 38a)

So it is possible, that even though these  Berachos comes in order to thank Hashem for what he already did for us (see Ibid) - you can’t really thank someone for something he didn’t do yet - when it comes to thanking Him for making bread, it would still make sense to thank him for the fact that he instilled in the earth, as a rule of nature, the constant and continuous power to grow crops - both in the past and in the future as well.

On the other hand, the blessing of ״מלביש ערומים״ comes in order to thank Hashem for giving us our clothing - which is not a constant and continuous rule of nature, and can always change by the individual in the future, and may therefore sound like a blessing in vain

Comment: pretty sure we had this already. @DonielF was it you?